# how to display text in text field based on check boxes?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

once multiple value selected from treeview list by using checkboxes , i want all selected values text to display in text field and close the treeview.I am new in Angularjs help will be appreciated.

Here is what i did so far ...

HTML

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="legalEnty"
                        ng-readonly="readOnly" ng-model="nonPersistentProcess.legalEnty"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" placeholder="LegalEntity"
                        ng-maxlength=100 required ng-click="showLegalEntityTreeView = {display: 'block' }"
                        data-required-msg="Legal Entity is required" name="legalEnty">
```

rating.js

```
var legalEntiryOptionsDataSource;

    $scope.treeOptions = {
      checkboxes: true,
      dataBound: function(e) {
        $scope.attachChangeEvent(e);
      }
    };

    $scope.attachChangeEvent = function(e) {
      var dataSource;
      dataSource = e.sender.dataSource;
      dataSource.bind('change', function(e) {
        var checkedNodes, i, nd, selectedNodes;
        selectedNodes = 0;
        checkedNodes = [];
        $scope.checkedNodeIds(dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
        i = 0;
        while (i < checkedNodes.length) {
          nd = checkedNodes[i];
          if (nd.checked) {
            selectedNodes++;
          }
          i++;
        }
        $scope.nonPersistentProcess.legalEnty = selectedNodes;
      });
    };


    legalEtityTreeOptions = TreeViewData.query({ id: 'LEGAL_ENTITY' }, function () {
      $scope.legalEntiryOptionsDataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({ data: legalEtityTreeOptions });
    });

    $scope.itemLegEntyTemplate = '<a ng-click="selectLeglEntyTree(this)" class="no-style">{{dataItem.text}}</a>';

    $scope.selectLeglEntyTree = function(object) {
      $scope.nonPersistentProcess.legalEnty = object.dataItem.text;
      $scope.processDTO.legalEnty = object.dataItem.id;
      $scope.showLegalEntityTreeView = {
        display: 'none'
      };
    };
```

Comment: ould you provide a fiddle or plunker as an example of your project that way would be easy to help

Comment: sorry not authorized to use plunker and fiddle

Comment: i see well the thing is that i dont know much about kendo integration with angular, but what i know is that by default if you insert dom elements in your angular app those elements will not be part of the app since angular doesnt compile them, so maybe your aproach is not the right one from the begining, but i dont really know hoes does it work with kendo

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your comment..